How to disable touchable opacity
how can I disable a touchable opacity for a minute after it is pressed.
let disable = false
<TouchableOpacity
     style={styles.btnSolid}
     onPress={() => {
        resetUserPswd(auth, Email, navigation);
        disable = false;
     }}
     disabled = {disable}
>
    <Text style={styles.btnTextSolid}>Send Email</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

thanks in advance.

You can use setTimeout like this:
  import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
  
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (disabled || !pressed) {
       return;
    }
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setDisabled(true);
    }, 60000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [pressed]);
  
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.btnSolid}
    onPress={() => {
      resetUserPswd(auth, Email, navigation);
      setPressed(true);
    }}
    disabled = {disabled}
  >
    <Text style={styles.btnTextSolid}>Send Email</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

